# AngularDart: input stops working when type set to number and compiled to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dart, angular-dart

I have a really weird problem with AngularDart. In my controller, I have a variable like this:

```
@NgController (...) 
class MyController
{
    num variable;
}
```

In the HTML, everything works as expected when I use `<input ng-model="ctrl.variable" />`. However, when I use `<input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.variable" />`, it only works in Chrome when compiled to JavaScript. In Firefox, an InvalidState exception is raised which I cannot even properly capture. The exact message is as follows:

```
"[Exception... "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"  code: "11" nsresult: "0x8053000b (InvalidStateError)"  location: "<unknown>"]

STACKTRACE:
"
```

Am I missing something? It works fine in Dartium and in Chrome (when compiled to JavaScript.) How am I supposed to get a numeric input field in the HTML when `type="number"` doesn't work? Omitting the `type="number"` is not a solution, as I get errors from String->num conversion otherwise.

Runnable triggering the exception: http://runnable.com/UxyECim2IlpC8nPn/angulardart-input%5Btype-%22number%22%5D-problem-indirection-for-dart2js

Simplified runnable which just produces NaN: http://runnable.com/Uxx69bm7tTNCuEcL/angulardart-input%5Btype-%22number%22%5D-problem-for-dart2js

AngularDart issue https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/694

Comment: I tried it in Firefox but I don't get the exception but it's not working properly either. The text on the right of the input always stays 'NaN' no matter what I write into the field.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found a way to reliably provoke the exception :) Might be also related to how the runnable is set up/initiated.

Comment: I still don't get the exception in Firefox. Instead of 'NaN' on the right I get '{{ctrl.currentItem.value}}' on the left.

Comment: Args, there's a typo in the html file. It tries to load inputtest.dart instead of main.dart, and hence it doesn't run at all. Should be fixed in a minute.

Comment: Now initially there is '23' on the left which changes to 'NaN' no matter what value I enter, but I still don't get an exception (Just a bunch of CSS errors from Runnables page code). Firefox 27 Linux

Comment: Interesting. I get the exception if I have the console open when reloading the page. Maybe it's a timing issue in the JavaScript VM?

Comment: I would create an issue https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug and it's fixed in Angular 0.9.11/0.10.0. See also:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/694
- http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15788